# Pip not working on Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, pip

I am trying to get Flask working under Cygwin, but I am unable to get pip to work. I succesfully managed to get easy_install working and even used that to install pip. As far as I can tell the install went well.

Here is the output:

```
$ easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.5.2
Processing pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg
pip 1.5.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/bin

Using /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

However when I try to do anything via pip, it doesn't do anything. For example:

```
$ pip install flask
```

There is no output. I'm really not sure where to start.

Comment: Does `which pip` output `/usr/bin/pip`?

Comment: Still nothing. Thanks

Comment: Try running `pip` with "extra verbose" output: `pip -vvv install flask`. Maybe it will give some hints.

Comment: It looks like following issue may be related to your problem: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1448

Comment: I'm afraid that `-vvv` still produced no output. I will have a look at that link you posted as it seems very similar to my experience. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately that even after updating cygwin, python and setup tools, I stil lcan't get pip to work

Comment: If you have time, then I'd suggest describing your problem in mentioned github issue. `pip` developers are more likely to help you (or actually fix the problem).

Answer (score 6):

I had this exact problem, and by following the link @iljau posted, I saw the recommendation to install the `libuuid-devel` and the `binutils` packages on Cygwin, and it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also had the no-output problem as well as it getting stuck at "GET ..." with the "-vvv" option. In my case it was due to an odd mix of folder permissions. (Perhaps due to running some applications as administrator from time-to-time.) By doing the following I was able to get it working:

1. (right click folder)
2. Properties
3. Security
4. Edit
5. (choose-your-user)
6. (choose-permissions-you-need)
7. Apply